# MikTex just closing without Error-Message

Tags: miktex

The log file says:

2020-12-04 22:00:00,806+0100 INFO  texworks - starting: MiKTeX TeXworks 0.6.5 (MiKTeX 20.11)

2020-12-04 22:01:19,920+0100 FATAL texworks.core - A required file system path could not be retrieved.

2020-12-04 22:01:19,920+0100 FATAL texworks.core - Data: nfolder="5", hr="-2147024891"

2020-12-04 22:01:19,920+0100 FATAL texworks.core - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\Utils\win\winUtils.cpp:72

2020-12-04 22:01:19,947+0100 FATAL texworks - MiKTeX exception: A required file system path could not be retrieved.
2020-12-04 22:01:19,947+0100 FATAL texworks -    Info: nfolder="5", hr="-2147024891"

2020-12-04 22:01:19,947+0100 FATAL texworks -  Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\Utils\win\winUtils.cpp

2020-12-04 22:01:19,947+0100 FATAL texworks -    Line: 72

2020-12-04 22:01:26,410+0100 INFO  texworks - starting: MiKTeX TeXworks 0.6.5 (MiKTeX 20.11)

2020-12-04 22:01:36,846+0100 **FATAL texworks.core - A required file system path could not be retrieved.**

2020-12-04 22:01:36,846+0100 FATAL texworks.core - Data: nfolder="5", hr="-2147024891"

2020-12-04 22:01:36,846+0100 FATAL texworks.core - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\Utils\win\winUtils.cpp:72

2020-12-04 22:01:36,871+0100 FATAL texworks - MiKTeX exception: A required file system path could not be retrieved.

2020-12-04 22:01:36,871+0100 FATAL texworks -    Info: nfolder="5", hr="-2147024891"

2020-12-04 22:01:36,871+0100 FATAL texworks -  Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\Utils\win\winUtils.cpp

2020-12-04 22:01:36,871+0100 FATAL texworks -    Line: 72

I have ALL newesst Updates.
Anybody an Idea?

Comment: Open an issue at the miktex github issue tracker.

Comment: Maybe this is related to https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/659 which was fixed in MikTeX 20.12? (Nevertheless updating from MikTeX 20.11 to MikTeX 20.12 is worth a try here.)

Comment: I solved the problem. I had in Windows-Defender a protection of some system-Folders so the program was not allowed to access the .. roaming  ... directory. I removed the Protection and the nit worked.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem. I had in Windows-Defender a protection of some system-Folders so the program was not allowed to access the .. roaming ... directory. I removed the Protection and the nit worked. –